# Crash Reporter strangely suggests Apport UgradeStatus is "No upgrade log present (probably a fresh install)"

Tags: crash, apport

After a crash probably relating to Firefox and or Suspend on a Ubuntu 14.04LTS install, Crash Reporter said that it was due to Apport and that Upgrade Status is "No upgrade log present (probably a fresh install)."

Well I'm unsure that this old install should reasonably be suggesting this.  Suspicious or anything?

What say you?

Comment: If this was a 12.04 or 13.10 that was release-upgraded to 14.04, then the string is inaccurate. Does not seem suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the installation of your *operating system*, not updates or "upgrades" to your installed programs.  If you fresh-installed 14.04, you'll see this. If you upgraded your operating system from a prior version, you'll see something different.

`apport` is the name of the error reporting program itself.

Comment: Thanks, Organic Marble.  Perfectly understood my concerns and pitched your answer precisely and fully.